# Does Swiffy supports actionscript 3.0 external classes?

Tags: class, actionscript, google-swiffy

I want to ask if Swiffy supports Actionscript external classes, or just timeline code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use greensock TweenMax external classes with swiffy. So YES!